# How do I join 4 python lists to create a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 lists, all of the same length and in the same order.  I want to join them all together to create a table.  A pandas dataframe will be the easiest way to work with the data so I'm wondering how I join all 4 lists?

Comment: How should the list be joined? Do you want it as 4 columns, or append them to have one long structure? Better to show a small example of the desired output

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2):

Since I have not understand the output, I think there may be two possible outcome which come to my mind currently. I am listing those below.

**First One:**

```
l = range(0, 10)
l2 = range(10, 20)
l3 = range(20, 30)
l4 = range(30, 40)
d = {'l1':l, 'l2':l2, 'l3':l3, 'l4':l4}
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(data=d)
```

this will create the dataframe like the below 
[image]

**Second type**:

```
df = DataFrame(data=[l,l2,l3,l4], index=('First','Second','Third','fourth'))
```

this will create a frame like this
[image]

Comment: Great - the 1st one is what I need.  I'd seen documentation on converting dictionaries to dataframes but I wasn't sure if I could do it direct from lists.  The other option was to create 4 dataframes from the individual lists and then join them but this didn't seem very efficient - the dictionary method will work better - thanks.